# JTransforms weird realInverse and realFoward

Tags: java, android

I met with a weird problem. Hope you could help me!
I tried to use JTransforms (a java FFT library) on android to process images. First, I do FFT (realFoward, I didn't use realFowardFull so as to save memory) to image R_pad, then I use IFFT(realInverse) to recover R_pad.

```
double[][] R_pad = ImagePad(R, picw, pich, kernelxsize, kernelysize);
int R_pad_size1 = R_pad.length;
int R_pad_size2 = R_pad[0].length;  
Log.d("R_pad", "R_pad origin:"+ R_pad[20][13]);
Log.d("R_pad", "R_pad origin:"+ R_pad[40][82]);
// do fft to R_pad
DoubleFFT_2D fft_pad = new DoubleFFT_2D(R_pad_size1,R_pad_size2);       
fft_pad.realForward(R_pad);
// do ifft
fft_pad.realInverse(R_pad, true);
Log.d("R_pad", "R_pad after1:" + R_pad[20][13]);
Log.d("R_pad", "R_pad after1:" + R_pad[40][82]);
```

According to theory, R_pad should be still the same as the original R_pad. However, I sampled some element and found that they are totally different (not close).

So I wrote a small matrix to see whether it's the problem of this library.

```
double[][] test = new double[][] {{121.0,151.0,132.0,190.0,90.0,71.0,0,0},{201.0,184.0,35.0,92.0,67.0,33.0,0,0},{93.0,104.0,27.0,35.0,88.0,204.0,0,0},{98.0,60.0,94.0,99.0,192.0,45.0,0,0}};
DoubleFFT_2D fft_test = new DoubleFFT_2D(4,8);
for(int j = 0; j <4; j++){
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){ 
      Log.d("test fft", "test fft:"+test[j][i]);
   }
}
fft_test.realForward(test);
fft_test.realInverse(test,true);

for(int j = 0; j <4; j++){
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
      Log.d("test fft", "test fft:"+test[j][i]);
   }
}
```

This time the result is correct! I am so confused where i am wrong about the first program. I am sure that R_pad 's width and height are 2048 and 1024, both the power of 2 (required by realForward and realInverse). Could somebody help me? Thanks a lot!

This is the website of JTransforms!
https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms

Answer (score 0):

From the jTransforms documentation, in the description of the realForward and realInverse methods for 2d double arrays:

"This method only works when the sizes of both dimensions are power-of-two numbers"

That is why your second example works fine, since 4 and 8 are both powers of two.

So I believe you should either zero-pad your data for the length of each dimension to be a power of two, or use complexForward and complexInverse.